# After installing ruby 1.9.3 rails 3.2.1, getting OpenSSL::SSL::SSLError: on simple requests

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, openssl, ruby-1.9.3

Got ruby 1.9.3/rails 2.3.1 installed via rvm (finally worked after installing openssl via rvm pkg.) but now getting OpenSSL::SSL:SSLError trying to connect to github (and probably anything else):

-->irb
1.9.3-p0 :001 > require 'open-uri'
1.9.3-p0 :002 > open('https://github.com/')
OpenSSL::SSL::SSLError: SSL_connect returned=1 errno=0 state=SSLv3 read server certificate B: certificate verify failed

-- Tried the solution in ["Certificate verify failed" OpenSSL error when using Ruby 1.9.3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8101377/certificate-verify-failed-openssl-error-when-using-ruby-1-9-3) but that did not work.

Not sure if the problem is in OpenSSL, but that seems to be the issue.

Comment: Did you add your public key to your github account?

Comment: Yes - This was all working fine pre ruby 1.9.3 install.

Comment: Which version of OpenSSL do you have? Looks like Ruby 1.9.2 works with OpenSSL 1.0.0 & 1.0.1, But Ruby 1.9.3 has a problem with 1.0.1. https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/openssl/+bug/965371 - seems to be a description of the problem

Answer (score 4):

There is a bunch of solutions that might work for you here :

http://railsapps.github.com/openssl-certificate-verify-failed.html

If it still doesn't work here what solved it for me :

```
rvm pkg install openssl
rvm install 1.9.3-p374 –with-openssl-dir=$rvm_path/usr
cd $rvm_path/usr/ssl
curl -O http://curl.haxx.se/ca/cacert.pem
mv cacert.pem cert.pem
```

Hope this helps, Vincent

Answer (score 0):

Ruby 1.9.3-p125 is released.

This release include a security fixes of the Ruby OpenSSL extension. And many bugs are fixed in this release.

http://www.ruby-lang.org/en/news/2012/02/16/ruby-1-9-3-p125-is-released/