# Error installing Ruby with rvm: "__rvm_make -j8"

Tags: ruby, macos, compiler-errors, openssl, rvm

I was trying to install latest stable Ruby versions (`3.1.x`, `3.2.x`) using [`rvm`](http://rvm.io/). However, the `rvm install` command of any of those versions fails when compiling Ruby. For instance, when trying to run

```
rvm install 3.1.4
```

I get the following output:

```
Searching for binary rubies, this might take some time.
No binary rubies available for: osx/13.5/arm64/ruby-3.1.4.
Continuing with compilation. Please read 'rvm help mount' to get more information on binary rubies.
Checking requirements for osx.
Updating certificates bundle '/opt/homebrew/etc/openssl@1.1/cert.pem'
Requirements installation successful.
Installing Ruby from source to: /Users/davidlj95/.rvm/rubies/ruby-3.1.4, this may take a while depending on your cpu(s)...
ruby-3.1.4 - #downloading ruby-3.1.4, this may take a while depending on your connection...
  % Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
                                 Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed
100 19.9M  100 19.9M    0     0  12.8M      0  0:00:01  0:00:01 --:--:-- 12.8M
No checksum for downloaded archive, recording checksum in user configuration.
/Users/davidlj95/.rvm/tmp/rvm_src_74481
ruby-3.1.4 - #extracting ruby-3.1.4 to /Users/davidlj95/.rvm/src/ruby-3.1.4 - please wait
ruby-3.1.4 - #configuring - please wait
ruby-3.1.4 - #post-configuration - please wait
ruby-3.1.4 - #compiling - please wait
Error running '__rvm_make -j8',
please read /Users/davidlj95/.rvm/log/1692282742_ruby-3.1.4/make.log

There has been an error while running make. Halting the installation.
```

Looked for errors in the file with `less -p error /Users/davidlj95/.rvm/log/1692282742_ruby-3.1.4/make.log`.

Seems the last error appearing before failing is related to OpenSSL:

```
ossl_ts.c:829:5: error: incomplete definition of type 'struct TS_verify_ctx'
    TS_VERIFY_CTX_set_certs(ctx, x509inter);
    ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
// ...
make[1]: *** [ext/openssl/all] Error 2
make: *** [build-ext] Error 2
+__rvm_make:0> return 2
1 warning and 1 error generated.
```

I am using an M1 / ARM chipset MacBook Pro. With macOS Ventura 13.5.

I've tried:

- Installing latest version appearing in `rvm list known`: `3.0.0`. It fails too.
- Going to the path where Ruby source code has been extracted and run `make -j8`. Fails because of same reason.
- `brew install openssl@1.1` after seeing you may need an older version of OpenSSL to build Ruby. It was already installed. No luck either.
- Ensuring the location of OpenSSL appearing in `Makefile` exists
- Install latest version of OpenSSL: `brew install openssl@3`. No luck either.

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37336573/unable-to-require-openssl-install-openssl-and-rebuild-ruby-preferred-or-use-n/42235933#42235933

Comment: It worked too, thanks! Didn't came across that post when had the issue :( I still prefer Ruby build guide suggestion though, so you can pick everything from `brew` if possible. I've seen other posts where `libyaml` fails. So looks like configuring everything to come from brew could give better results in the general case

Answer (score 27, accepted):

As the [Ruby build guide suggests](https://github.com/ruby/ruby/blob/30a5b94517699589f6943163cd6b92f2f6c0023f/doc/contributing/building_ruby.md#:%7E:text=typically%20using%20Homebrew%20on%20macOS), export the configuration arguments environment variable for the pre-compilation step indicating where libraries installed by [Homebrew](https://brew.sh/) are installed. You can do so by running:

```bash
export CONFIGURE_ARGS=""
for ext in openssl readline libyaml zlib; do 
  CONFIGURE_ARGS="${CONFIGURE_ARGS} --with-$ext-dir=$(brew --prefix $ext)" 
done
```

Then, run the `rvm install` command. Compilation succeeded and that Ruby version was installed. Worked for several Ruby versions.

Comment: do you put that in your .zshrc? and keep it there?

Comment: I don't install Ruby often so honestly I just go here and copy/paste this before the `rvm install` everytime. Placing that in `.zshrc` feels a bit dirty, as other software may pick the `CONFIGURE_ARGS` environment variable and fail because of the value in there. If you use this often, maybe you could add an alias in your `.zshrc` though. Like: `alias rvm-preinstall=export CONFIGURE_ARGS=""; for ext...`. Then, run `rvm-preinstall` before installing with `rvm install`