# How to solve OpenSSL error during install of ruby 3.1.3 for Mac

Tags: ruby, macos, openssl, jekyll, apple-silicon

I'm getting the below error when I try to install `ruby-install ruby 3.1.3` (following [instructions to install Jeykll](https://jekyllrb.com/docs/installation/macos/)). I think the issue is [this link](https://github.com/rbenv/ruby-build/wiki#macos) says ruby versions greater than 3.1 require OpenSSL 3, but when I run `ruby-install ruby 3.1.3`, it installs OpenSSL 1.1, which I think is being linked to and causing the install to fail. `RUBY_CONFIGURE_OPTS` is set correctly as per the github insructions.

```
ossl_ts.c:829:5: error: incomplete definition of type 'struct TS_verify_ctx'
    TS_VERIFY_CTX_set_certs(ctx, x509inter);
    ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
./openssl_missing.h:215:46: note: expanded from macro 'TS_VERIFY_CTX_set_certs'
#  define TS_VERIFY_CTX_set_certs(ctx, crts) TS_VERIFY_CTS_set_certs(ctx, crts)
                                             ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
./openssl_missing.h:195:52: note: expanded from macro 'TS_VERIFY_CTS_set_certs'
#  define TS_VERIFY_CTS_set_certs(ctx, crts) ((ctx)->certs=(crts))
                                              ~~~~~^
/opt/homebrew/Cellar/openssl@3/3.1.3/include/openssl/ts.h:407:16: note: forward declaration of 'struct TS_verify_ctx'
typedef struct TS_verify_ctx TS_VERIFY_CTX;
               ^
1 warning and 1 error generated.
make[2]: *** [ossl_ts.o] Error 1
make[1]: *** [ext/openssl/all] Error 2
make: *** [build-ext] Error 2
!!! Compiling ruby 3.1.3 failed!
```

How would I solve this?

Relevant links I've tried following steps of that don't seem to solve the problem: [1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76922732/error-installing-ruby-with-rvm-rvm-make-j8), [2](https://github.com/rbenv/ruby-build/discussions/2245), [3](https://github.com/rbenv/ruby-build/discussions/2053), [4](https://github.com/ruby/openssl/issues/199), [5](https://github.com/rbenv/ruby-build/discussions/2245)

Answer (score 17, accepted):

It could be an issue with the arguments. Try the below

```
export CONFIGURE_ARGS=""                                                   
for ext in openssl readline libyaml zlib; do
  CONFIGURE_ARGS="${CONFIGURE_ARGS} --with-$ext-dir=$(brew --prefix $ext)"
done
```

Comment: This also worked for me

Comment: worked like charm !!! many thanks 

Comment: Thanks! Worked perfectly for me as well.