# OpenSSL error when authenticating user for DocusignAPI

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, openssl, ssl-certificate, docusignapi

We are trying to use composite templates (fillable PDFs) and embedded signing using the REST API. We are using the docusign_rest gem in conjuction with our custom code to create composite templates and embedded signing. The docusign_rest gem is used for authentication and is giving the following error:

> OpenSSL::SSL::SSLError (SSL_connect returned=1 errno=0 state=SSLv3 read server certificate B: certificate verify failed)

On the local dev machine, we simply provided path to a certificate file at the time of starting the dev server, but on a remote machine this is not feasible.

Is it possible to skip the SSL check for a demo purpose? [This SO link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17458711/self-signed-certificate-with-demo-docusignapi) seems to suggest that it is possible. If yes, then how can we achieve that?

If not, then is there a quick way to fix it or do we have to install SSL certificates and configure the server to read those?

We are using ruby 1.9.3 , rails 3.2.11 and Apache2 (so that would mean enabling the SSL module).

Answer (score 0):

I believe for demo (demo.docusign.net) you can use https OR http.  What happens if you simply use http?  Does that resolve your SSL error?

In either case, you'll eventually need to resolve this though because for production (www.docusign.net) you need to use https.  The problem is most likely in your Ruby code or with your certificate.  For testing purposes I'd try making a cURL request through the command line to see if that works.

[See here for some examples of making DocuSign REST API calls using cURL](http://www.docusign.com/developer-center/quick-start/first-api-call)

Comment: I used a rest client to make the call with http