# Twilio app; twilio-ruby (3.4.2), SSL error

Tags: ruby, twilio

I have followed the sample code on the [Twilio github page](https://github.com/twilio/twilio-ruby) and it doesn't work. In my Rails console, it looks like this:

```
irb(main):039:0> require 'twilio-ruby'
=> nil
irb(main):040:0* account_sid='xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx'
=> "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx"
irb(main):041:0> auth_token='yyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyy'
=> "yyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyy"
irb(main):042:0> client=Twilio::REST::Client.new account_sid, auth_token
=> <Twilio::REST::Client @account_sid=AC1322312300a752f6e84a8254535ecce5>
irb(main):043:0> client.account.sms.messages.create :from=>'16135551234', :to=>'16135551212',     :body=>"Ada is fat"
OpenSSL::SSL::SSLError: SSL_connect returned=1 errno=0 state=SSLv3 read server certificate B:  certificate verify failed
    from C:/Ruby192/lib/ruby/1.9.1/net/http.rb:678:in `connect'
    from C:/Ruby192/lib/ruby/1.9.1/net/http.rb:678:in `block in connect'
    from C:/Ruby192/lib/ruby/1.9.1/timeout.rb:44:in `timeout'
    from C:/Ruby192/lib/ruby/1.9.1/timeout.rb:87:in `timeout'
    from C:/Ruby192/lib/ruby/1.9.1/net/http.rb:678:in `connect'
    from C:/Ruby192/lib/ruby/1.9.1/net/http.rb:637:in `do_start'
    from C:/Ruby192/lib/ruby/1.9.1/net/http.rb:626:in `start'
    from C:/Ruby192/lib/ruby/1.9.1/net/http.rb:1168:in `request'
    from C:/Ruby192/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rest-client-1.6.7/lib/restclient/net_http_ext.rb:51:in `request'
    from C:/Ruby192/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/twilio-ruby-3.4.2/lib/twilio-ruby/rest/client.rb:214:in `connect_and_send'
    from C:/Ruby192/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/twilio-ruby-3.4.2/lib/twilio-ruby/rest/client.rb:138:in `block (2 levels) in <class:Client>'
    from C:/Ruby192/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/twilio-ruby-3.4.2/lib/twilio-ruby/rest/list_resource.rb:73:in `create'
    from (irb):43
    from C:/Ruby192/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.0.11/lib/rails/commands/console.rb:44:in `start'
    from C:/Ruby192/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.0.11/lib/rails/commands/console.rb:8:in `start'
    from C:/Ruby192/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.0.11/lib/rails/commands.rb:23:in `<top (required)>'
    from script/rails:6:in `require'
    from script/rails:6:in `<main>'irb(main):044:0>
```

What else do I need to do to get twilio-ruby to successfully send a text message? I have used these numbers and credentials for incoming calls, so they are good.

** EDIT Dec 24, 2011 *********
Instead of running this code on my PC, I deployed it to heroku.com. Then I had no SSL errors and I was able to place outgoing calls. I'm very puzzled.

Comment: Heroku has the proper CA certificate files in the right place for ruby to find them.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This shouldn't be a problem in twilio-ruby versions starting with 3.5.0. It "just works" out of the box now.

With twilio-ruby versions before 3.5.0 there wasn't an SSL CA cert bundle packaged with the gem. So the only way to "fix" this was to either point your client at a cert bundle at initialization time:

```
client = Twilio::REST::Client.new sid, token, :ssl_ca_file => '/path/to/file'
```

or to disable SSL verification altogether (not recommended in production):

```
client = Twilio::REST::Client.new sid, token, :ssl_verify_peer => false
```

Comment: The second one got me going with twilio running on my test server (a.k.a. laptop).

Comment: self-assign `ssl_ca_file` solved error 'OpenSSL::SSL::SSLError: SSL_connect returned=1 errno=0 state=error: certificate verify failed'

Answer (score 1):

You may be missing root certificate files.  This typically shouldn't be necessary but you can try disabling certificate verification by adding these lines before making the call:

```
require 'open-uri'
require 'openssl'
OpenSSL::SSL::VERIFY_PEER = OpenSSL::SSL::VERIFY_NONE
```

Comment: I tried this, but I got exactly the same error. Do I need to install extra gems, or do some other configuration jiggery-pokery?

Comment: You can disable SSL peer verification by passing :ssl_verify_peer => false as a parameter to the Client constructor: client = Twilio::REST::Client.new sid, token, :ssl_verify_peer => false

Comment: Hi Andrew Benton. Your suggestion worked. If you post it as a proper answer I'll accept it.

Comment: It might work, but disabling certificate checks leaves you vulnerable to man-in-the-middle attacks. I would like to know how to add the missing root certificate files.