# MassPayment on Rails function misunderstanding

Tags: ruby-on-rails, paypal

I want to use MassPayments.

I have function in my controller:

```
def send_money(to_email, how_much_in_cents, options = {})
  credentials = {
    "USER" => 'pro._1342094044_biz_api1.gmail.com',
    "PWD" => '1342094095',
    "SIGNATURE" => 'AMVxTgrWf6tUTF0Rf0y4QsqTFFAcApSXcqINQj2b2-a5wFhIx3UG87E- ',
  }

  params = {
    "METHOD" => "MassPay",
    "CURRENCYCODE" => "USD",
    "RECEIVERTYPE" => "EmailAddress",
    "L_EMAIL0" => to_email,
    "L_AMT0" => ((how_much_in_cents.to_i)/100.to_f).to_s,
    "VERSION" => "51.0"
  }
  endpoint = RAILS_ENV == 'production' ? "https://api-3t.paypal.com" : "https://api3t.sandbox.paypal.com"
  url = URI.parse(endpoint)
  http = Net::HTTP.new(url.host, url.port)
  http.use_ssl = true
  all_params = credentials.merge(params)
  stringified_params = all_params.collect { |tuple| "#{tuple.first}={CGI.escape(tuple.last)}" }.join("&")

  response = http.post("/nvp", stringified_params)
end
```

I'm calling this function only for one user(for the start):

```
send_money('pro_1342434702_biz@gmail.com',1000)
```

But at this moment it gives me error:

```
uninitialized constant MerchantsController::RAILS_ENV
```

So I tried to change this line:

```
endpoint = RAILS_ENV == 'production' ? "https://api-3t.paypal.com" : "https://api-3t.sandbox.paypal.com"
```

but all my attempts failed. Errors that I got during experiments - environment or SSL sertificate errors.

When I leave only :

```
endpoint = "https://api-3t.sandbox.paypal.com"
```

I get error :

```
SSL_connect returned=1 errno=0 state=SSLv3 read server certificate B: certificate verify failed
```

Can someone help ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think there is two questions in you post. First, to test if you are in production mode, you can do something like this :

```
endpoint = ENV["RAILS_ENV"] == 'production' ? "https://api-3t.paypal.com" : "https://api-3t.sandbox.paypal.com"
```

The other question is a problem with SSL. You can find a solution here : [SSL_connect returned=1 errno=0 state=SSLv3 read server certificate B: certificate verify failed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4528101/ssl-connect-returned-1-errno-0-state-sslv3-read-server-certificate-b-certificat)

Comment: SSL_connect returned=1 errno=0 state=SSLv3 read server certificate B: certificate verify failed showing me.

Comment: Can you check what is returned by ENV["RAILS_ENV"]?

Comment: You can go in debug mode (check it on google) or simple add `puts ENV["RAILS_ENV"]` in your code an check logs.

Comment: Did you run your application with `rails start -e production`?

Comment: no. I found SSL_connect returned=1 errno=0 state=SSLv3 read server certificate B: certificate verify failed error could be caused by old rails. So now I'm uodating them. I will try what you are talking about after install.Thanks for help.

Comment: Maybe, I could try to deploy it and look if there will be error ?

Comment: E:\paypal_permission>rails start -e production
Error: Command not recognized

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/13958/discussion-between-dougui-and-denys-medynskyi)