# Rails 4 and Ruby 2 Net/HTTP SSL Request: OpenSSL::SSL::SSLError: SSL_connect returned=1 errno=0 state=SSLv2/v3 read server hello A: unknown protocol

Tags: ssl, openssl, ruby-on-rails-4, ruby-2.0, net-http

This is nearly a duplicate of:

[SSL_connect returned=1 errno=0 state=SSLv3 read server certificate B: certificate verify failed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4528101/ssl-connect-returned-1-errno-0-state-sslv3-read-server-certificate-b-certificat)

but **specific to a Rails 4 and Ruby 2 environment.**  I figure it is appropriate to make a new question because the solutions that worked on my machine for previous environments no longer appear to work after the updates to Rails and Ruby.

### The Problem

When making a Net/HTTP SSL request to the tune of:

```
api_uri = URI("http://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/token")
https = Net::HTTP.new(api_uri.host, api_uri.port)
https.use_ssl = true
https.ca_file = '/usr/local/etc/openssl/cert.pem' if Rails.env == "development"
https.request_get(api_uri.path)
```

I receive the

```
OpenSSL::SSL::SSLError: SSL_connect returned=1 errno=0 state=SSLv2/v3 read server hello A: unknown protocol
```

error.  I've tried out the solutions in the referenced question that worked in the previous environments, to no avail.

Answer (score 0):

Try setting the certificate in environment i.e `ENV` see it that help something like this

```
ENV['SSL_CERT_FILE'] = "your certificate path"
```

Answer (score 0):

Looks like it a typo - it should be an https:// protocol in the URI on the first line (and not http://)