# SSL_connect returned=1 errno=0 state=SSLv3 read server certificate B: certificate verify failed ONLY WHEN PROXYING

Tags: ruby, ssl, openssl, net-http, charles-proxy

This post nearly duplicates a number of other posts, including [Rails 4 and Ruby 2 Net/HTTP SSL Request: OpenSSL::SSL::SSLError: SSL_connect returned=1 errno=0 state=SSLv2/v3 read server hello A: unknown protocol](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18321740/rails-4-and-ruby-2-net-http-ssl-request-opensslsslsslerror-ssl-connect-ret) and [SSL_connect returned=1 errno=0 state=SSLv3 read server certificate B: certificate verify failed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4528101/ssl-connect-returned-1-errno-0-state-sslv3-read-server-certificate-b-certificat), but with one key difference: the "certificate verify failed" error only happens when proxied via an SSL proxy ([Charles](http://www.charlesproxy.com/)), and only in the latest version of Ruby.

Specifically, this (non-proxied) code works:

```
  uri = URI.parse('https://www.ibm.com')
  http = Net::HTTP.new(uri.host, uri.port, nil)
  http.use_ssl = true
  http.start { |agent| agent.get(uri.path) }
```

and this (proxied) code fails with a "certificate verify failed" error:

```
  uri = URI.parse('https://www.ibm.com')
  http = Net::HTTP.new(uri.host, uri.port, "localhost", 8888)
  http.use_ssl = true
  http.start { |agent| agent.get(uri.path) }
```

#### the puzzle

The error ONLY appears when going through the proxy in the current versions of Ruby/OpenSSL.  In particular:

- There's no error when NOT going through the proxy, which leads me to think that the local certs are valid.
- There's no error when going through the proxy with Firefox or `curl -v https://www.ibm.com/`, which leads me to think that the Charles certs are valid.
- There's no error going through the proxy on an earlier version of Ruby / OpenSSL (see below for the two environments).

All this makes me suspect an actual Ruby bug rather than a problem with my certs, but I'd be happy to be shown otherwise.

#### the current environment

I'm observing the error with this environment:

```
$ system_profiler SPSoftwareDataType | grep "System Version"
    System Version: OS X 10.8.5 (12F45)
$ ruby --version ; openssl version ; gem list | grep http
ruby 2.0.0p247 (2013-06-27) [x86_64-darwin12.4.0]
OpenSSL 1.0.1e 11 Feb 2013
http-cookie (1.0.2)
http_router (0.10.2)
net-http-digest_auth (1.4)
net-http-persistent (2.9)
ntlm-http (0.1.1)
```

#### the previous environment

The error does not appear with a slightly older version of ruby/OpenSSL:

```
$ ruby --version ; openssl version ; gem list | grep http
ruby 2.0.0p0 (2013-02-24 revision 39474) [x86_64-darwin10.8.0]
OpenSSL 0.9.8y 5 Feb 2013
http_router (0.11.0, 0.10.2)
httpauth (0.2.0)
net-http-digest_auth (1.2.1)
net-http-persistent (2.8)
ntlm-http (0.1.1)
```

Comment: Did you install the Charles CA cert? (from the help menu)

Comment: @pguardiario Yes.  (I don't think Charles would have worked with FireFox and curl otherwise...)

Comment: Are you ssl proxying (aka mitm proxying)

Comment: @pguardiario: precisely. I'm developing a script to automatically login to an SSL site, so I'm using Charles to record the interactions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What is going on here is that Charles cannot provide you with a valid certificate for "https://www.ibm.com", because whatever certificate you set up Charles with (or if Charles creates its own certificate) it cannot be for the "www.ibm.com" name AND certified by a trusted certificate authority. That's why the connection fails if the client verifies the the certificate, and works if you skip verification with

```
http.verify_mode = OpenSSL::SSL::VERIFY_NONE
```

It probably worked with the older version of ruby because "net/https" was adjusted to verify
certificates by default only recently.

Comment: I've switched the checkmark to your answer since it's complete and offers an explanation as to why it behaved the way it did.  Thanks.

Comment: @Tanel: I would ask you to tone down a bit. And yes: I know what turning off certificate verification means. I even explain that (to a degree) in my answer. Yet the OP wants to know what is the difference between ruby versions, and I tell exactly that.

Answer (score 0):

I seem to recall needing to point to that cert in an ENV var. If you're not really concerned with verifying, it's easier to just:

```
http.verify_mode = OpenSSL::SSL::VERIFY_NONE
```

Comment: That works, but I'm not sure why.  I was under the impression that it was the proxy providing the certs -- which certs is the http agent verifying (or not verifying, in this case)?

Comment: That's a good question. I always assumed it was the initial connection between ruby and Charles.