# SSL_connect returned=1 errno=0 state=error: certificate verify failed

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Hi guys i'm new on RoR and have an question.

I'm trying to integrate an API from Coinmarketcap. I had an good start but now i have an problem with certificate verify failed.

For sure i researched about it and found this: [RestClient::SSLCertificateNotVerified: SSL_connect returned=1 errno=0 state=SSLv3 read server certificate B: certificate verify failed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34629333/restclientsslcertificatenotverified-ssl-connect-returned-1-errno-0-state-sslv)

but it didn't solve my problem.

**Here my Code:**

```
require 'rubygems'
require 'httparty'

url = 'https://api.coinmarketcap.com/v2/listings/'
response = HTTParty.get(url)
response.parsed_response

class Coinmarketcap
  include HTTParty
  base_uri 'api.coinmarketcap.com'

def listings
  self.class.get('/v2/listings/')
  end
end


coinmarketcap = Coinmarketcap.new
puts coinmarketcap.listings
```

Comment: did you try https://www.engineyard.com/blog/ruby-ssl-error-certificate-verify-failed

Comment: or this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19463827/ssl-connect-returned-1-errno-0-state-sslv3-read-server-certificate-b-certificat