# JSON gem install error: unable to download data

Tags: ruby, json, windows, windows-7, rubygems

I'm using:

- Windows 7 SP1
- Ruby 2.0.0p598 (2014-11-13) [i386-mingw32]
- Gem Version 2.0.14
- DevKit: Ruby 2.0.0: mingw64-32-4.7.2

When testing in the Ruby environment and running the JSON gem install, I receive this error:

```
C:\RoW\Ruby200\devkit>gem install json --platform=ruby

ERROR:  Could not find a valid gem 'json' (>= 0), here is why:
Unable to download data from https://rubygems.org/ - SSL_connect returned=1 errno=0 state=SSLv3
read server certificate B: certificate verify failed (https://rubygems.org/latest_specs.4.8.gz)
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [SSL\_connect returned=1 errno=0 state=SSLv3 read server certificate B: certificate verify failed](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4528101/ssl-connect-returned-1-errno-0-state-sslv3-read-server-certificate-b-certificat)

Comment: This is a duplicate of the above-mentioned question.

Answer (score 2):

SSL error is due to a change in rubygems.org. You can see a solution here : https://gist.github.com/luislavena/f064211759ee0f806c88

You need to change your SSL certificate

**Edit:**

**Manual solution to SSL issue**

If you have read the above detail that describe the issue, thank you.

Now, you want to manually fix the issue with your installation.

Steps are simple:

```
Step 1: Obtain the new trust certificate
Step 2: Locate RubyGems certificate directory in your installation
Step 3: Copy new trust certificate
Step 4: Profit
```

**Step 1: Obtain the new trust certificate**

If you've read the previous sections, you will know what this means (and shame on you if you have not).

We need to download [AddTrustExternalCARoot-2048.pem](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/rubygems/rubygems/master/lib/rubygems/ssl_certs/AddTrustExternalCARoot-2048.pem).

Use the above link and place/save this file somewhere you can later find easily (eg. your Desktop).

IMPORTANT: File must have .pem as extension. Browsers like Chrome will try to save it as plain text file. Ensure you change the filename to have .pem in it after you have downloaded it.
**Step 2: Locate RubyGems certificate directory in your installation**

In order for us copy this file, we need to know where to put it.

Depending on where you installed Ruby, the directory will be different.

Take for example the default installation of Ruby 2.1.5, placed in C:\Ruby21

Open a Command Prompt and type in:

```
C:\>gem which rubygems
C:/Ruby21/lib/ruby/2.1.0/rubygems.rb
```

Now, let's locate that directory. From within the same window, enter the path part up to the file extension, but using backslashes instead:

```
C:\>start C:\Ruby21\lib\ruby\2.1.0\rubygems
```

This will open a Explorer window inside the directory we indicated.

**Step 3: Copy new trust certificate**

Now, locate ssl_certs directory and copy the .pem file we obtained from previous step inside.

It will be listed with other files like GeoTrustGlobalCA.pem.

**Step 4: Profit**

There is actually no step 4. You should be able to install Ruby gems without issues now.

Answer (score 0):

If you have one [Ruby193 install folder with executables] in your C:drive, then you should change to that directory and execute the same command in the bin folder...

User@Computer-Name /c/Ruby193/bin  ./gem install json --platform=ruby

$ ./gem install json --platform=ruby
Fetching: json-1.8.1.gem (100%)
Building native extensions.  This could take a while...
ERROR:  Error installing json:
        ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

```
    c:/Ruby193/bin/ruby.exe extconf.rb
```

creating Makefile

make
generating generator-i386-mingw32.def
compiling generator.c
generator.c:1:0: error: CPU you selected does not support x86-64 instruction set

generator.c:1:0: error: CPU you selected does not support x86-64 instruction set

make: *** [generator.o] Error 1

Gem files will remain installed in c:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/json-1.8.
1 for inspection.
Results logged to c:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/json-1.8.1/ext/json/ext/ge
nerator/gem_make.out