# Windows 7 64-bit: Could not find a valid gem 'compass' (>= 0), here is why: Unable to download data from https://rubygems.org/

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, windows, windows-7, compass

I cannot install compass. I want to install compass on my project so when I try to update, I get this:

> c:\wamp\www\danjasnowski.com>gem install compass
> ERROR:  Could not find a valid gem 'compass' (>= 0), here is why: Unable to download data from https://rubygems.org/ - SSL_connect returned=1 errno=0 state=SSLv3 read server certificate B: certificate verify failed (https://api.rubygems.org/specs.4.8.gz)

Also.. my current version.

> c:\wamp\www\danjasnowski.com>gem --version
>
> 2.4.1

and

> irb(main):001:0> RUBY_VERSION
>
> => "2.0.0"
>
> irb(main):002:0> RUBY_RELEASE_DATE
>
> => "2014-05-08"
>
> irb(main):003:0> RUBY_PLATFORM
>
> => "x64-mingw32"
>
> irb(main):004:0> RUBY_PATCHLEVEL
>
> => 481
>
> irb(main):005:0>

Answer (score 63, accepted):

Try upgrading your SSL certificates.

1. Download http://curl.haxx.se/ca/cacert.pem
2. Save this file anywhere you want, such as:

   ```
   C:\cacert.pem
   ```
3. On the command line, tell Ruby where to find the cert file, such as:

   ```
   set SSL_CERT_FILE=C:\cacert.pem
   ```
4. Try again.

   ```
   gem install compass
   ```
5. If it works, you can make the cert file permanent by adding it in your control panel.

Credit and more info: https://gist.github.com/fnichol/867550

Comment: @PratikPatil Good idea. Can you try it? If it works, please feel free to edit my answer and/or post your results in a comment so I can edit my answer.T Thanks!

Comment: It is December 2016 and this solution is still working. I used path C:\Ruby200-x64

Answer (score 2):

Just an additional option for lazy people who don't want to deal with the SSL certificates, you can just uninstall and re-install the latest ruby environment. I used to have 1.8 something and reinstalling to 2.2.1 did the trick.

[link for windows](http://rubyinstaller.org/downloads/)

Comment: Can you tell me some command to uninstall ruby which I can run from command prompt. @1mike12

Answer (score 1):

If there are still guys like me that can't find solution in any of the comments before mine, here's how I found my working way:

I went to rubygems.org/pages/download and downloaded zipped file. Then I unpacked it somewhere on my C: partition and opened it once I unpacked it. Find a file "setup.rb" and double click on it, it will install something, I don't remember. I guess ruby gems. Then close everything, go again and open cmd on windows and try typing "gem install sass". It worked for me. Sass installed. :)

Hope I will help someone, because I lost my mind looking for solution to this problem whole day today. :)

Answer (score 0):

My solution was this:
I uninstalled my current ruby installation which is for x64 system and replaced it with ruby x86/32bit installer and followed the steps given by @joelparkerhenderson.

Though I have x64 system, this is the only solution that worked for me.