# Cannot install SASS on windows 7 (64 bit)

Tags: ruby, windows, rubygems, sass, installation

I am trying to get **SASS** installed on my windows machine at work, however after installing ruby I cannot seem to install it ..

- **Ruby Version** - **2.1.5**

The error I am getting when running `gem install sass` on the command prompt :

> ERROR: Could not find a valid gem 'SASS' ,.= 0., here is why:
>
> Unable to download data from https://rubygems.org/ - SSL_connect returned=1 errno=0 state=SSLv3
>
> read server certificate B: certificate verify failed https://api.rubygems.org/latest_specs.4.8.gx

Has anyone else encountered this? Know a way around it??

Comment: Probably this could help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27435841/windows-7-64-bit-could-not-find-a-valid-gem-compass-0-here-is-why-unab

Comment: slightly off topic, but I would recommend to uninstall Windows rather then..whatever you do

Comment: Unfortunately @YevgeniyAnfilofyev this did not work :(

Comment: @AndreyDeineko this is not an option unfortunately. I would use *nix if I could!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out the latest download of ruby is having issues with it's SSL cert .. Installed an older version - **works a treat**