# "Unable to download data from https://rubygems.org/" because "certificate verify failed"

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I added this code to my `mydbs_controller.rb` as instructed on the Rails tutorial:

```
def create
  @mydbs = Mydb.new(params[:mydb])

  @mydb.save
  redirect_to @mydb
end
```

I run my database and come up with this error:

> ```
> The controller-level `respond_to' feature has been extracted to the 
> `responders` gem. Add it to your Gemfile to continue using this feature:
> gem 'responders', '~> 2.0'
> Consult the Rails upgrade guide for details.
> ```

So I added gem 'responders', '~> 2.0' to my gemfile and tried a bundle install.

I run into another error telling me

> Make sure that `gem install responders -v '2.1.0'` succeeds before bundling.

After running that I'm left with yet another error

> `ERROR:  Could not find a valid gem 'responders' (= 2.1.0), here is why:
>             Unable to download data from https://rubygems.org/ - SSL_connect returned=1 errno=0 state
>   =SSLv3 read server certificate B: certificate verify failed (https://api.rubygems.org/specs.4.8.gz)`

Comment: possible duplicate of [Windows 7 64-bit: Could not find a valid gem 'compass' (>= 0), here is why: Unable to download data from https://rubygems.org/](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27435841/windows-7-64-bit-could-not-find-a-valid-gem-compass-0-here-is-why-unab)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So my problem was that i needed to be running on ruby version 2.2.2. However that update (only for windows users) pulled a lot of errors that I found to not appear on the mac.

Answer (score 1):

I meet same question.
Then I change the gem source  from 
"https://rubygems.org/" to "http://rubygems.org/"