# Update OPENSSL in ruby

Tags: ruby, chef-infra, chef-solo

I'm working with Chef and I'd been working with remote_file

```
remote_file '/Users/username/dir/abc.js'
  source 'https://raw.githubusercontent.com/benkeen/d3pie/0.1.8/d3pie/d3pie.js'
  owner 'username'
  group 'group'
  mode '0755'
  action :create
end
```

`$chef-solo -c solo.rb`
This gives me error:

```
 OpenSSL::SSL::SSLError
    ----------------------
    SSL_connect returned=1 errno=0 state=error: certificate verify failed
```

I did investigate error and found out that openssl I'm using is older version `OpenSSL 0.9.8za 5 Jun 2014` and links below helped me to figure out the SSL error.

https://github.com/phrase/phraseapp-ruby/issues/1

According to the discussion they told to upgrade `openssl` using `brew upgrade openssl`. This did upgrade `openssl` coz `openssl version` gave me `OpenSSL 1.0.2d 9 Jul 2015`.

But when I check ruby version of openssl using command

```
$ruby -ropenssl -e "puts OpenSSL::OPENSSL_VERSION"
OpenSSL 0.9.8za 5 Jun 2014
```

How do I update my open ssl so the `ruby -ropenssl -e "puts OpenSSL::OPENSSL_VERSION"` points to `1.0.2d version`

Comment: What operating system are you using?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4528101/ssl-connect-returned-1-errno-0-state-sslv3-read-server-certificate-b-certificat

Comment: Thanks, this link helped me a lot. Thanks a ton..