# API call throwing SSL_connect error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, api, ssl, osx-elcapitan

I'm getting this error:

```
Not a duplicated SSL_connect returned=1 errno=0 state=error: certificate verify failed OS El Capitan
```

While using this code to make API calls:

```
require 'json'
require 'net/http'
url = 'https://touch-rate.com/o/analytics/dashboard?api_key='+ENV["API_KEY"]+'&app_id='+ENV["APP_ID"]%>
resp = Net::HTTP.get_response(URI.parse(url))
dashboard = JSON.parse(resp.body)
```

My server was recently changed to a secure server and since then it has been throwing the above error.

I've have tried every multiple options on Stackoverflow, but nothing seems to work, can somebody help me with why I'm getting this error?

Thank you

Answer (score -1):

You will have to basically bypass the SSL ceritificate validation while connecting to a webservice running on SSL. You can do so by using the following snippet of code

```
 uri = URI.parse(url)
 http = Net::HTTP.new(uri.host, uri.port)
 http.use_ssl = (uri.scheme == 'https')
 http.verify_mode = OpenSSL::SSL::VERIFY_NONE
 request = Net::HTTP::Post.new(uri.request_uri)
 response = http.request(request)
 dashboard = JSON.parse(resp.body)
```

So basically `http.verify_mode = OpenSSL::SSL::VERIFY_NONE` is the line of code that bypasses the certificate validation.
I hope it helps

Comment: Thanks a lot! that worked for me :)

Comment: Could you please accept the answer so that others  would come to know that this solution works.

Comment: Disabling SSL is a dangerous option -- you're basically opening yourself up to man in the middle attacks. These problems are likely related to an OSX upgrade, see here for more: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4528101/ssl-connect-returned-1-errno-0-state-sslv3-read-server-certificate-b-certificat