# OpenSSL::SSL::SSLError when GCM.send_notification

Tags: ruby-on-rails, openssl, google-cloud-messaging

I'm using [GCM gem](https://github.com/spacialdb/gcm) to send push notifications to Android Devices. In production server, notifications are sent perfectly, but when I try to send push notifications in my local, I get the following error:

> OpenSSL::SSL::SSLError: SSL_connect returned=1 errno=0 state=SSLv3 read server certificate B: certificate verify failed

Note that `GCM API KEY` is set with the same key as production server, and I'm using the same `send_notification` params that production server. I also add my local IP address in `Google Developer Console project credentials` (daily updated).

What I am missing?

NOTE: Using `RoR v3.2.13`, `Ruby v2.0.0`, `OSx El Capitan`, and I have installed `openssl v1.0.2a-1`

Comment: This may be a duplicate of [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4528101/ssl-connect-returned-1-errno-0-state-sslv3-read-server-certificate-b-certificat).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, the problem was that I haven't installed `curl-ca-bundle`, like many similar questions point. When I tried to install `curl-ca-bundle` with `brew`, I found that the [package was removed](https://github.com/smdahlen/vagrant-digitalocean/issues/123). After a bit of research, I could install the `ca-cert` on my Mac [following this steps.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31003583/4084391)

Hope this help someone in future.