# In rubyonrails localhost and stripe, how to deal with Could not verify Stripe's SSL certificate?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ssl, stripe-payments

I had trouble with this the whole day, I still can't fix it.

I'm testing my Rails app locally on localhost:3000.
I click on the button for the stripe payment, I enter the test card number etc and press enter.
And everything is fine (green button with arrow to say it's ok) then I should have a redirect, but instead I have an error page with this :

"Could not verify Stripe's SSL certificate. Please make sure that your network is not intercepting certificates. (Try going to https://api.stripe.com/v1 in your browser.) If this problem persists, let us know at support@stripe.com. (Network error: SSL_connect returned=1 errno=0 state=SSLv3 read server certificate B: certificate verify failed)"

I looked up on Stripe, and I see that the API call was processed but nothing appears in "customers", so basically the transaction didn't work.

Anyone know how could I fix this ?
Thanks

Comment: This should help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4528101/ssl-connect-returned-1-errno-0-state-sslv3-read-server-certificate-b-certificat

Comment: Question - is this happening on every API request?