# rake neo4j:install giving ArgumentError

Tags: neo4j, neo4j.rb

I am working on a Windows 8 PC and am new to web development.

I am following [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=n0P0pOP34Mw&feature=iv&src_vid=bDjbqRL9HcM&annotation_id=annotation_2875848113) tutorial to build a neo4j rails application. When I type the following into Powershell:

> rake neo4j:install[community-latest]

I get the following error

```
DL is deprecated, please use Fiddle
Install Neo4j (development environment)...
rake aborted!
ArgumentError: wrong number of arguments (1 for 0)

Tasks: TOP => neo4j:install
```

I tried downloading neo4j to my device and followed some instructions on manually configuring the rails app to connect with the server, but ran into issues there as well. I uninstalled Neo4j subsequently.

Any advice is appreciated! Let me know if you need to see other parts of the application. Thank you.

--- TRACE ---

> DL is deprecated, please use Fiddle
>
> ** Invoke neo4j:install (first_time)
>
> ** Execute neo4j:install Retrieving latest version... rake aborted!
>
> OpenSSL::SSL::SSLError: SSL_connect returned=1 errno=0 state=SSLv3
>   read server certificate B: certificate verify failed
>
> C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.1.0/lib/ruby/2.1.0/net/http.rb:920:in
>   `connect'
>
> C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.1.0/lib/ruby/2.1.0/net/http.rb:920:in `block
>   in connect'
>
> C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.1.0/lib/ruby/2.1.0/timeout.rb:76:in `timeout'
>
> C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.1.0/lib/ruby/2.1.0/net/http.rb:920:in
>   `connect'
>
> C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.1.0/lib/ruby/2.1.0/net/http.rb:863:in
>   `do_start'
>
> C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.1.0/lib/ruby/2.1.0/net/http.rb:852:in `start'
>
> C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.1.0/lib/ruby/2.1.0/open-uri.rb:313:in
>   `open_http'
>
> C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.1.0/lib/ruby/2.1.0/open-uri.rb:724:in
>   `buffer_open'
>
> C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.1.0/lib/ruby/2.1.0/open-uri.rb:210:in `block
>   in open_loop'
>
> C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.1.0/lib/ruby/2.1.0/open-uri.rb:208:in `catch'
>
> C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.1.0/lib/ruby/2.1.0/open-uri.rb:208:in
>   `open_loop'
>
> C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.1.0/lib/ruby/2.1.0/open-uri.rb:149:in
>   `open_uri'
>
> C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.1.0/lib/ruby/2.1.0/open-uri.rb:704:in `open'
>
> C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.1.0/lib/ruby/2.1.0/open-uri.rb:34:in `open'
>
> C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.1.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/neo4j-core-5.0.10/lib/neo4j/tasks/neo4j_server.rake:87:in
>   `block in  get_edition'
>
> C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.1.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/neo4j-core-5.0.10/lib/neo4j/tasks/neo4j_server.rake:84:in
>   `gsub'
>
> C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.1.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/neo4j-core-5.0.10/lib/neo4j/tasks/neo4j_server.rake:84:in
>   `get_edit ion'
>
> C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.1.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/neo4j-core-5.0.10/lib/neo4j/tasks/neo4j_server.rake:96:in
>   `block (2  levels) in '
>
> C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.1.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/rake-10.5.0/lib/rake/task.rb:240:in
>   `call'
>
> C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.1.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/rake-10.5.0/lib/rake/task.rb:240:in
>   `block in execute'
>
> C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.1.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/rake-10.5.0/lib/rake/task.rb:235:in
>   `each'
>
> C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.1.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/rake-10.5.0/lib/rake/task.rb:235:in
>   `execute'
>
> C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.1.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/rake-10.5.0/lib/rake/task.rb:179:in
>   `block in invoke_with_call_chai n'
>
> C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.1.0/lib/ruby/2.1.0/monitor.rb:211:in
>   `mon_synchronize'
>
> C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.1.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/rake-10.5.0/lib/rake/task.rb:172:in
>   `invoke_with_call_chain'
>
> C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.1.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/rake-10.5.0/lib/rake/task.rb:165:in
>   `invoke'
>
> C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.1.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/rake-10.5.0/lib/rake/application.rb:150:in
>   `invoke_task'
>
> C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.1.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/rake-10.5.0/lib/rake/application.rb:106:in
>   `block (2 levels) in top
>   _level'
>
> C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.1.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/rake-10.5.0/lib/rake/application.rb:106:in
>   `each'
>
> C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.1.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/rake-10.5.0/lib/rake/application.rb:106:in
>   `block in top_level'
>
> C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.1.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/rake-10.5.0/lib/rake/application.rb:115:in
>   `run_with_threads'
>
> C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.1.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/rake-10.5.0/lib/rake/application.rb:100:in
>   `top_level'
>
> C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.1.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/rake-10.5.0/lib/rake/application.rb:78:in `block in run'
>
> C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.1.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/rake-10.5.0/lib/rake/application.rb:176:in
>   `standard_exception_hand ling'
>
> C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.1.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/rake-10.5.0/lib/rake/application.rb:75:in `run'
>
> C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.1.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/rake-10.5.0/bin/rake:33:in
>   `'
>
> C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.1.0/bin/rake:23:in `load'
>
> C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.1.0/bin/rake:23:in `'

Comment: Unfortunately I don't have a windows machine currently to test on ;(  Could you run `rake neo4j:install[community-latest] --trace` so that you can get the stack trace and then edit your question with the result so that I can take a look?  Either make a comment here so that I get a notification or join us on http://gitter.im/neo4jrb/neo4j so that I can help you in real(ish)-time

Comment: I dug into it a little and I think it was an authentication problem in neo4j-rake_tasks/windows_server_manager.rb. The nt-admin method was running a "reg query" on an HKU registry. Even though I was working from an admin account, I didn't have access to that registry. When I returned "true" from nt-admin, the error turned into an SSL encryption key error like the one in the link below. I have not tried out the solution in the link so I don't know if it works. [link]http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4528101/ssl-connect-returned-1-errno-0-state-sslv3-read-server-certificate-b-certificat[link]