# Cannot Update Gems on Mac

Tags: terminal, rubygems, fastlane

I'm trying to update a gem:

```
sudo gem update fastlane
```

But each time I try to do this update, or any update on any gem I get:

```
Updating installed gems
ERROR:  While executing gem ... (Gem::RemoteFetcher::FetchError)
    SSL_connect returned=1 errno=0 state=SSLv3 read server certificate B: certificate verify failed (https://api.rubygems.org/specs.4.8.gz)
```

I've been searching around for a fix all day and cannot find anything that has worked. It worked last week, and it works on a different Mac. This seems to have started randomly.

Answer (score 0):

This is probably due to the web service responding with a certificate signed against a CA that your SSL library cannot verify.

If you are using RVM you can try this:

`rvm osx-ssl-certs update all`

Or you can try this if it's just using MacPorts

`sudo port install curl-ca-bundle`

There is more information here: [SSL_connect returned=1 errno=0 state=SSLv3 read server certificate B: certificate verify failed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4528101/ssl-connect-returned-1-errno-0-state-sslv3-read-server-certificate-b-certificat)