# Rails Error: certificate verify failed...I've tried everything

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ssl, devise, certificate, google-authentication

So I'm trying to get Google authentication to work with rails and devise. I followed [this github setup](https://github.com/zquestz/omniauth-google-oauth2) and when the user gets redirected after a successful login I get this error:

```
SSL_connect returned=1 errno=0 state=SSLv3 read server certificate B: certificate verify failed
```

I've literally tried every solution I can find online and nothing seems to work. I downloaded the new cert which is in /usr/local/etc/openssl/certs/cert.pem and this is in my devise.rb:

```
  config.omniauth :google_oauth2, "92780849937-vk78tsfss43p1m9k95ijfhimi422hfh7.apps.googleusercontent.com", "oEM4yvhazRJBgL7ANtpVtpU5", { :client_options => {:ssl => {:ca_path => "/usr/local/etc/openssl/certs"}}}
```

I'm running ruby 2.1.0 and Rails 4.2.4
Is there something I'm missing? Maybe a different solution for this version of rails?

I added this to my application.rb so I can keep working but obviously its pretty horrible hahahaha

```
require 'openssl'
OpenSSL::SSL::VERIFY_PEER = OpenSSL::SSL::VERIFY_NONE
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can add the gem 'certified' to your Gemfile to fix this issue.
Check their [Github page](https://github.com/stevegraham/certified)
And this [SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4528101/ssl-connect-returned-1-errno-0-state-sslv3-read-server-certificate-b-certificat)

Comment: Wow I spent like 6 hours trying to figure this out and that one line worked perfectly. Thank you so much!