# Why can't I install rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, git-bash

Whenever I try to follow [this](http://installfest.railsbridge.org/installfest/windows), on step 6 I enter the code and won't install, it only tells me the following below in the commandline.

```
Could not find a valid gem 'rails' (>= 0), here is why:
          Unable to download data from https://rubygems.org/ - SSL_connect returned=1 errno=0 state=SSLv3 read server certificate B: certificate verify failed (https://api.rubygems.org/specs.4.8.gz)
```

I am brand new to commandline and I have 0 idea what this means or why it won't let me install rails. Can anyone help?

I should also add when I try to check version of ruby it gives me the proper version. But when I try to check rails I get.

```
C:\Sites>rails -v
The system cannot find the path specified.
```

**UPDATE**

Using Windows 10

Ruby version 2.2.4

I don't know how to tell if a firewall is stopping me

Using a home network

I just tried to run this:

```
C:\Sites>gem update --system
ERROR:  While executing gem ... (Gem::RemoteFetcher::FetchError)
    SSL_connect returned=1 errno=0 state=SSLv3 read server certificate B: certificate verify failed (https://api.rubygems.org/specs.4.8.gz)
```

and

```
C:\Sites>gem install rails
ERROR:  Could not find a valid gem 'rails' (>= 0), here is why:
          Unable to download data from https://rubygems.org/ - SSL_connect returned=1 errno=0 state=SSLv3 read server certificate B: certificate verify failed (https://api.rubygems.org/specs.4.8.gz)
```

When I go to the rails environment configuration I noticed it doesn't show a version number for rails but shows a bat file.

```
ruby:
  bin:        C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.0.0/bin/ruby.exe
  version:    ruby 2.2.4p230 (2015-12-16 revision 53155) [i386-mingw32]

rails:
  bin:        C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.0.0/bin/rails.bat
  version:
```

Comment: What os are you using? What version of ruby are you using?

Comment: Are you behind a firewall stopping you to visit https://rubygems.org/?

Comment: From where are you trying to install rails? Home or corporate network?

Comment: Windows 10, 2.2.4, possibly I don't know how to tell if its stopping me, home

Comment: This may help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4528101/ssl-connect-returned-1-errno-0-state-sslv3-read-server-certificate-b-certificat

Comment: None of that makes any sense at all to me

Comment: How about this (Windows specific)? http://stackoverflow.com/a/7536952/472768

Comment: That didn't work either. Same result

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is for fixing ssl errors in windows
1) Download [certificate](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/rubygems/rubygems/master/lib/rubygems/ssl_certs/index.rubygems.org/GlobalSignRootCA.pem)
2) save it to `C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.0.0/ssl_certs/GlobalSignRootCA.pem`
3) create environment variable `SSL_CERT_FILE` set it to `C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.0.0/ssl_certs/GlobalSignRootCA.pem`
4) then gem install rails

Comment: This lists Ruby2.0.0/ssl_certs/ but I am using ruby2.2.0 and I dont see a folder named ssl_certs. Do I make one?

Comment: create ssl_certs folder inside your Ruby2.2.0 and change environment variable accordingly

Answer (score 0):

You can follow as steps below:

```
1. gem sources -a http://rubygems.org
2. gem install rails
```

Comment: Nevermind. So it installed it but now I am getting the same error whenever I do anything else and it is warning me I may be subject to a MITM attack....

Answer (score 0):

As a workaround you could try to replace in your Gemfile

```
source 'https://rubygems.org'
```

with

```
source 'http://rubygems.org'
```

so that the SSL connection error dissipates. This snippet of code is located at the top of your Gemfile

Note - you are getting the MITM (man in the middle) attack warning, because you are using HTTP, rather than HTTPS (which is encrypted). This should be fine, it is just a warning and unlikely that any actual attack would occur. To get rid of this warning, follow the steps [**Here**](https://gist.github.com/fnichol/867550)

Or, you can simply run `gem sources -a http://rubygems.org` so that your gems (including the rails 5.0.0.1 gem) are downloaded via http rather than https

Although, if you want to use the encrypted download via SSL, follow [this guide](https://gist.github.com/luislavena/f064211759ee0f806c88) on GitHub that leads you through the process of installing a certificate to trust RubyGems.org

Answer (score 0):

So I did the following and it fixed the issue (seemingly)

for Windows with PowerShell installed

Installing Windows PowerShell

Paste this 1line code in command console: (WIN + R, cmd)

```
powershell -Command "& {$fname='cacert.pem'; $outpath=\"$($(Get-ChildItem Env:USERPROFILE).Value)/$fname\"; Invoke-WebRequest http://curl.haxx.se/ca/$fname -OutFile \"$outpath\"; [Environment]::SetEnvironmentVariable('SSL_CERT_FILE', \"$outpath\", 'User')}"
```

Script will do:

1. Download http://curl.haxx.se/ca/cacert.pem
2. Save it as `%USERPROFILE%/cacert.pem ( C:\Users\__you__\cacert.pem)`
3. Set persistent environment variable for current user `SSL_CERT_FILE` as `%USERPROFILE%/cacert.pem`