# Xamarin: read server certificate B: certificate verify failed

Tags: macos, ssl, jenkins

Maybe someone of can help me with this problem: I have a Jenkins job running on a Mac machine. The project is developed on Xamarin. In the job, the build is started like this (`Execute shell script`):

```
# Installing dependencies
brew bundle
bundle install

# Run fastlane
bundle exec fastlane ci
```

During compilation, I get these error messages:

```
[16:48:42]: -----------------------------------------
[16:48:42]: --- Step: make_changelog_from_jenkins ---
[16:48:42]: -----------------------------------------
[16:48:42]: Unable to read/parse changelog from jenkins: SSL_connect returned=1 errno=0 state=SSLv3 read server certificate B: certificate verify failed
[16:48:42]: ------------------------------
[16:48:42]: --- Step: appcenter_upload ---
[16:48:42]: ------------------------------
[16:48:43]: Starting release upload...
[16:48:43]: Uploading release binary...
[16:49:29]: Binary uploaded
[16:49:30]: Release committed
[16:49:33]: Public Download URL: YYYY
[16:49:33]: Release XXXXX was successfully distributed to group "Collaborators"
[16:49:34]: Error adding to destination 400: {"release_notes"=>"Retrieving changelog failed.", "code"=>"bad_request", "message"=>"Destination does not exist."}
[16:49:34]: dSYM is found
```

The Jenkins server has a self-signed certificate which It has set up. I already found a way to solve this `read server certificate B: certificate verify failed` error: [SSL_connect returned=1 errno=0 state=SSLv3 read server certificate B: certificate verify failed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4528101/ssl-connect-returned-1-errno-0-state-sslv3-read-server-certificate-b-certificat#)

So I logged in onto the Mac server and downloaded the certificate from Jenkins with:

```
openssl s_client -connect JENKINSSERVER:8443 2>/dev/null | sed -ne '/-BEGIN CERTIFICATE-/,/-END CERTIFICATE-/p' > jenkins_cert.pem
```

Then I changed the shell script in Jenkins, which starts the job to this:

```
export SSL_CERT_FILE=/Users/user/Downloads/jenkins_cert.pem

if [ ! -f "$SSL_CERT_FILE" ]; then
    echo "Error: Could not find SSL_CERT_FILE '$SSL_CERT_FILE'"
    exit 1
fi

# Installing dependencies
brew bundle
bundle install

# Run fastlane
bundle exec fastlane ci
```

The error still exists. It would be good if someone could give me a hint where to look. If you need other information, I can provide it to you.