# Omniauth Facebook authentication on localhost

Tags: ruby-on-rails, facebook, localhost, omniauth

I am trying to set up Omniauth as described in this [Railscast](http://railscasts.com/episodes/236-omniauth-part-2). While it works with Twitter, I am unable to get it working with Facebook. I also set up 'http://localhost:3000' as siteurl and 'localhost' as domain but still see the following error message in the browser:

```
Invalid redirect_uri: Given URL is not allowed by the Application configuration.
```

Does anyone of you have any suggestions on how to fix this? Thanks in advance.

Comment: I don't think I added any configuration except 'http://0.0.0.0:3000/'. When you start up your local Rails server, what IP address does it say it's using?

Comment: It says http://0.0.0.0:3000. What excactly did you add in your host file?

Comment: I've never modified my hosts file. It has 127.0.0.1 for localhost.

Answer (score 32, accepted):

Take a look at the redirect in the URI. Mine read localhost:3000 so I changed the Site URL to "http://localhost:3000/" and it worked.

Comment: Now it works! Thank your very much. After that i ran into this problem http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3977303/omniauth-facebook-certificate-verify-failed . I followed the advise given in the answer and another error occured: No route matches "/auth/failure".. Hope to find a solution for that, too.

Comment: Is there any way to test in localhost and still have the app working on production environment? I mean, I can only access my app through facebook and I want to keep testing it locally without having to change the redirect destiny on Facebook.

Comment: finally someone in stack with a perfect answer for this shit! thanks

Comment: @fwuensche - You probably sorted this out, but easiest way is to just create two separate apps. You should store your key and secret as Environment Vars, this way you don't have the keys in your source code repo, and you can develop easily on localhost and production ;)

Answer (score 28):

Here's what worked for me.

Right now Facebook does not allow setting the Site Domain to an IP, so it's not possible to set the Site URL to `http://127.0.0.1:3000/` because then Facebook will complain that the URL does not match the domain.

So in your Facebook App set the:

```
Site URL: http://localhost:3000/
Domain: localhost
```

When you access the app on your dev machine make sure you type in localhost:3000 in the browser. If you use 127.0.0.1:3000 OmniAuth will use that in the callback url it sends to Facebook and then Facebook will throw the error Ryan mentions above.

Comment: where are you supposed to set those? In which file?

Comment: @kibaekr in your facebook app's dashboard https://developers.facebook.com/apps/YOUR_APP_ID/summary

Comment: Is there any way to test in localhost and still have the app working on production environment? I mean, I can only access my app through facebook and I want to keep testing it locally without having to change the redirect destiny on Facebook

Answer (score 15):

I switch to http://lvh.me:3000 in my local browser to test facebook locally.  Then in facebook app settings, make lvh.me your domain.

lvh.me is a registered domain pointing to 127.0.0.1 that a developer bought to test subdomains locally.

Answer (score 7):

Try using

```
http://0.0.0.0:3000/
```

for the 'Site URL'. This works for me. (Also, I don't have anything in the 'Site Domain' field.)

Comment: still getting the same error after following your advise. did you add any line to your hostfile? i'm starting to lose my sanity because of this.. :(

Comment: Rails finally not convert `127.0.0.1` into `localhost`, can grant access now, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

If you are on OSX you can use pow http://pow.cx/ to rename localhost to

```
http://yourapp-dev
```

(is not really renamed, it's added)

you can set that as a valid domain name on facebook.

Comment: Have you tried that? Because I had a problem with it. Facebook didn't allow .dev address.