# How to get rid of OpenSSL::SSL::SSLError

Tags: ruby-on-rails, facebook, omniauth, omniauth-facebook

I am trying to authenticate users with Facebook using OmniAuth. Initially, it was working, but along the way it just stopped working and started to give me this error message:

> OpenSSL::SSL::SSLError SSL_connect
>   returned=1 errno=0 state=SSLv3 read
>   server certificate B: certificate
>   verify failed

The same code works well for Twitter and I can't seem to understand why it doesn't work for Facebook. I have looked online for help, but I haven't been successful.

This is the link to the website I am building: http://www.bestizz.com/
And this url would give you the error message: http://www.bestizz.com/auth/facebook

Comment: We can't tell you what code to change if you don't show us the code you already have. :) Perhaps [this helps](http://www.ruby-forum.com/topic/176626#773356)?

Comment: Sorry, this is a link to my code and details of the problem [link](http://www.ruby-forum.com/topic/1538936#993973) @brandonTilley

Comment: are you getting a stack trace? There are a few libraries down the stack (OmniAuth, OAuth2, Faraday, etc.) and if you have a stack trace it would probably help a lot.

Comment: @brandonTilley, sorry, for going round and round. New to this forum, by the way, this is a link to my framework stack trace. [link](http://www.ruby-forum.com/topic/1538936#994260)

Comment: No problems ^_^ Added an answer, finally :) Good luck

Answer (score 27):

Ruby cannot find any root certificates. Here is an option for **debugging** purposes. Put following code at the begining of your script:

```
   require 'openssl'
   OpenSSL::SSL::VERIFY_PEER = OpenSSL::SSL::VERIFY_NONE
```

Comment: This should not be considered an option. Fix it properly or don't even bother using SSL.

Comment: As noted, this is for debugging or development ONLY. Do NOT use this code in production.

Comment: Indeed, _for debugging_, when I'm communicating with servers I haven't installed certs on, I do this. On my Ruby, I get a dynamic constant assignment error, so I monkey patched it instead, so something like `module OpenSSL; module SSL; VERIFY_PEER = OpenSSL::SSL::VERIFY_NONE; end; end`

Comment: I definitely think that in your answer you should include why that is very insecure.

Comment: Not just that is a security violation, it's even useless to the point that it doesn't tell WHERE to put this code.

Comment: The code is meant to go at the very beginning of the script.

Answer (score 9):

Add the following code to config/initializers/fix_ssl.rb

```
require 'open-uri'
require 'net/https'

module Net
  class HTTP
    alias_method :original_use_ssl=, :use_ssl=

    def use_ssl=(flag)
      self.ca_file = "/etc/pki/tls/certs/ca-bundle.crt"  # for Centos/Redhat
      self.verify_mode = OpenSSL::SSL::VERIFY_PEER
      self.original_use_ssl = flag
    end
  end
end
```

Note:

Many operating systems already come with a supplied certificate bundle. 
For example in Red Hat Enterprise Linux and CentOS it's installed in:

```
/etc/pki/tls/certs/ca-bundle.crt
```

For Ubuntu its at:

```
/etc/ssl/certs/ca-certificates.crt
```

Comment: I can't find initializers directory in my .config directory (I'm on ubuntu), could you help me with it?

Comment: config/initializers directory comes under your Rails application folder structure. This solution is for Rails application.

Comment: For me it was enough to set environmet variable in redhat `export SSL_CERT_FILE='/etc/pki/tls/certs/ca-bundle.crt'`

Comment: the line `self.ca_file = "/etc/pki/tls/certs/ca-bundle.crt` helped me with my ruby console app. None of the other solution worked. I guess, ssls wasn't able to know, which certificate file to use.

Answer (score 7):

I've been facing the same problem after updating Ruby running on Yosemite, but while trying to authenticate with Google.

Following this: `https://toadle.me/2015/04/16/fixing-failing-ssl-verification-with-rvm.html` seemed to solve my problem.

For the sake of history I'll quote:

> So the rvm-installed ruby does look into the wrong directory for certificates whereas the OSX-ruby will look into the correct one. In it's case that is a OSX system-directory.
>
> So the rvm-installed ruby is the problem.
>
> This discussion on Github finally gave the solution: Somehow RVM comes with a precompiled version of ruby that is statically linked against an openssl that looks into /etc/openssl for it's certificates.
>
> What you wanna do is NOT TO USE any of the precompiled rubies and rather have ruby compiled on your local machine, like so: rvm install 2.2.0 --disable-binary

In the end, I had to run:

```
rvm uninstall ruby-2.2.4
rvm install ruby-2.2.4 --disable-binary
gem pristine --all
```

Hope this helps

Answer (score 6):

Looks like SSL verification is failing for Facebook. I'm no OpenSSL master, but I think this should work for you.

Assuming you're using an up-to-date version of OmniAuth (>= 0.2.2, I assume you are) and a version of Faraday >= 0.6.1 (the stack trace says you are), you can pass the location of your CA certificates bundle. Modify your OmniAuth setup for Facebook accordingly:

```
Rails.application.config.middleware.use OmniAuth::Builder do
  provider :facebook, 'appid', 'appsecret', {:scope => 'publish_stream,email', :client_options => {:ssl => {:ca_path => '/etc/ssl/certs'}}}
  # other providers...
end
```

and replace `'/etc/ssl/certs'` with the path to your bundle. If you need one, I believe [this file](http://curl.haxx.se/ca/cacert.pem) will work for you--just put it somewhere, give it necessary permissions, and point your app at it.

Thanks to Alex Kremer at [this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3977303/omniauth-facebook-certificate-verify-failed/5618072#5618072) for the detailed instructions.

Comment: yeah...@brandon...it works perfectly. Thanks very much. It looks like i developed that problem after i upgraded my gems...Its an issue with Omniauth 0.2.1 - 0.2.2.

Answer (score 1):

Do this, this will get ride of the certificate error with openssl

```
sudo curl http://curl.haxx.se/ca/cacert.pem -o /opt/local/etc/openssl/cert.pem
```

Comment: This looks like it's for a self installed, maybe MacPorts OpenSSL ? any idea for standard Mac OS X or homebrew?

Comment: This worked for me with RVM on Mountain Lion: `curl http://curl.haxx.se/ca/cacert.pem -o ~/.rvm/usr/ssl/cert.pem`

Comment: @Lachlan Cotter, many thanks!  I was finally able to get [RailsApps Project](http://railsapps.github.com/) apps working with Rails 3.2.8 on Mountain Lion thanks to this command.

Answer (score 1):

This link should work. https://gist.github.com/fnichol/867550 Just follow the instructions. You will need to download Rails installer and run two command line functions.

Answer (score 0):

An ugly workaround I just did is to override the class in Net::HTTP and set the variable which tells it to not verify ssl certs:

```
    require 'net/http'
    require 'openssl'

    class Net::HTTP   
        alias_method :orig_connect, :connect

        def connect
          @ssl_context.verify_mode = OpenSSL::SSL::VERIFY_NONE
          orig_connect
        end
    end
```

I did it this way because I don't want to muck with the source code of the gem which calls the gem which calls the gem which calls Net::HTTP. I should really go back and figure out how to nudge it to look at a separate cacert.pem file instead. I can't modify the server's cacert.pem file, or that would be the best route.

Comment: No need to open a class and override a method -- you can change the `verify_mode` directly on the HTTP object you create: `http.verify_mode = OpenSSL::SSL::VERIFY_NONE`

Comment: @MikeA. that only works if you're the one creating the `Net::HTTP` instance.

Comment: —1 for `OpenSSL::SSL::VERIFY_NONE`.