# OpenSSL::SSL::SSLError - SSL_connect returned=1 errno=0 state=SSLv3 read server certificate B: certificate verify failed

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I get this error:

```
OpenSSL::SSL::SSLError

SSL_connect returned=1 errno=0 state=SSLv3 read server certificate B: certificate verify failed

Rails.application.config.middleware.use OmniAuth::Builder do  
  provider :facebook, 'MY_APPID', 'SECRET', {:scope => 'publish_stream,email', :client_options => {:ssl => {:ca_path => "#{Rails.root}/config/cacert.pem"}}}
end
```

The action:

```
def callback
  session['fb_auth'] = request.env['omniauth.auth']
  session['fb_token'] = session['fb_auth']['credentials']['token']
  session['fb_error'] = nil
render :text => request.env['omniauth.auth'].to_yaml  
end
```

I have been trying some solutions to this problem like:

```
Rails.application.config.middleware.use OmniAuth::Builder do  
  provider :facebook, 'MY_APPID', 'SECRET', {:scope => 'publish_stream,email', :client_options => {:ssl => {:verify => false}}}
end
```

and

```
Rails.application.config.middleware.use OmniAuth::Builder do  
  provider :facebook, 'MY_APPID', 'SECRET', {:scope => 'publish_stream,email', :client_options => {:ssl => {:ca_path => "#{Rails.root}/config/ca-bundle.crt"}}}
end
```

Where ca-bundle is: http://certifie.com/ca-bundle/ca-bundle.crt.txt

```
Rails.application.config.middleware.use OmniAuth::Builder do  
  provider :facebook, 'MY_APPID', 'SECRET', {:scope => 'publish_stream,email', :client_options => {:ssl => {:ca_path => "#{Rails.root}/config/cacert.pem"}}}
end
```

Where cacert.pem is: http://curl.haxx.se/ca/cacert.pem

I am using Windows  7. Does anybody have a solution on this or I am doing something wrong. What is the differens between `.pem` and `.crt`?

Comment: Hey, have your problem got solved? If yes, accept the correct answer. If there is no correct answer, add your answer which got it solved so that everyone can get benefit from it.

Comment: The question is like 3 years old, can´t remember if I got an answer i could use. Properly not else I would have accepted it.

Answer (score 1):

Ruby cannot find any root certificates.

Here is another option for debugging purposes:

```
require 'openssl'
OpenSSL::SSL::VERIFY_PEER = OpenSSL::SSL::VERIFY_NONE
```

Source: https://stackoverflow.com/a/12032944/1047207 (My answer to similar question)

You may want to take a look at this [Blog](http://martinottenwaelter.fr/2010/12/ruby19-and-the-ssl-error/) also.