# create p12 certificate with production certificate

Tags: ios, ssl, push-notification

I using following comment to generate `p12` file,

```
openssl x509 -in developer_identity.cer -inform DER -out developer_identity.pem -outform PEM

openssl pkcs12 -nocerts -in mykey.p12 -out mykey.pem

openssl pkcs12 -export -inkey mykey.pem -in developer_identity.pem -out iphone_dev.p12
```

`p12` file was generated successfully for development but it wont work for distribution...

I got error in the last step, asking password for `mykey.pem` file after give password it shows

```
"No certificate matches private key"

Enter pass phrase for mykey.pem:
No certificate matches private key
```

Can any one help me with this?

Comment: Try to generate p12 file from keychain (with 2 requested certificates). http://www.raywenderlich.com/32960/apple-push-notification-services-in-ios-6-tutorial-part-1 this can help you out

Comment: see this link. it may help you. http://stackoverflow.com/a/10045210/510814

Answer (score 0):

I change .cer file for distribution but forget get .p12 file from keychain for distribution...

after get .p12 file from keychain its working.

Comment: Can I make my comment as an answer so you can accept it? If I helped you