# iOS push notification doesn't work with distribution certificate

Tags: ios, xcode, cordova, notifications, certificate

I used cordova plugin phonegap-plugin-push and I sent a push notification on a test device with development certificate and it works.
Instead, when I try with distribution certificate (on the appStore published on store) doesn't work. The token is generated, but the notification doesn't reach device with alert badge or sound.
(I exported correctly the certificate in p12 and enabled push notification both on the apple developer and Xcode).
Hope someone can helps me.
Thank you!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [iOS Push Notifications not working for Distribution](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9920587/ios-push-notifications-not-working-for-distribution)

Answer (score 1):

**POSSIBLE ISSUE:**

Make you sure to use LIVE gateway URL, i.e. ssl://gateway.push.apple.com:2195 and not sandbox URL.

I will suggest to make a IS_LIVE Flag like below:

```
if($this->isLive){
                $connection = stream_socket_client(
                'ssl://gateway.push.apple.com:2195', $err,
                $errstr, 60, STREAM_CLIENT_CONNECT|STREAM_CLIENT_PERSISTENT, $ctx);
            }
            else{
                $connection = stream_socket_client(
                'ssl://gateway.sandbox.push.apple.com:2195', $err,
                $errstr, 60, STREAM_CLIENT_CONNECT|STREAM_CLIENT_PERSISTENT, $ctx);
            }
```

Comment: thank you a lot for your reply! Do you know where exactly set this gateway  into the cordova plugin?

Comment: This has to be in your Server Code, which sends the Push Notification to your iOS device.

Comment: unfortunately still doesn't work. Could be a bug of cordova plugin?

Comment: no, in that case, you wouldn't have received any notification in development mode.

Comment: got it. So it's a problem of distribution certificate, I think.

Comment: I found the problem, It was an error in the backend code sending push notification.