# Rails 3 - Omniauth & Devise - SSL Certificate error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ssl, ssl-certificate, omniauth

I setup my rails app, integrate Omniauth & Devise.
But when my callback function (/auth/:provider/callback) after login from facebook/google/yahoo, i see a SSL certificate error.
I also download cacert.pem & config in omniauth.rb, but this error still remain.

Can anyone help me?

Comment: Possible duplicate:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5711190/how-to-get-rid-of-opensslsslsslerror/36075541#36075541