# Rails omniauth facebook SSL handshake failure

Tags: ruby-on-rails, facebook, ssl, omniauth, poodle-attack

My app has been running fine for months, and all of a sudden logging in just doesn't work, i get this:

`` 2014-10-18T18:09:33.971670+00:00 app[web.1]: Faraday::SSLError (SSL_connect returned=1 errno=0 state=SSLv3 read server hello A: sslv3 alert handshake failure):
2014-10-18T18:09:33.971672+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/ruby-2.0.0/lib/ruby/2.0.0/net/http.rb:918:in `connect'
2014-10-18T18:09:33.971674+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/ruby-2.0.0/lib/ruby/2.0.0/net/http.rb:918:in `block in connect'
2014-10-18T18:09:33.971675+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/ruby-2.0.0/lib/ruby/2.0.0/timeout.rb:52:in `timeout'
2014-10-18T18:09:33.971676+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/ruby-2.0.0/lib/ruby/2.0.0/net/http.rb:918:in `connect'
2014-10-18T18:09:33.971678+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/ruby-2.0.0/lib/ruby/2.0.0/net/http.rb:862:in `do_start'
2014-10-18T18:09:33.971679+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/ruby-2.0.0/lib/ruby/2.0.0/net/http.rb:851:in `start'
2014-10-18T18:09:33.971680+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/ruby-2.0.0/lib/ruby/2.0.0/net/http.rb:1367:in `request'
2014-10-18T18:09:33.971682+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/newrelic_rpm-3.8.1.221/lib/new_relic/agent/instrumentation/net.rb:27:in `block (2 leve
ls) in request_with_newrelic_trace'
2014-10-18T18:09:33.971683+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/newrelic_rpm-3.8.1.221/lib/new_relic/agent.rb:404:in `disable_all_tracing'
2014-10-18T18:09:33.971685+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/newrelic_rpm-3.8.1.221/lib/new_relic/agent/instrumentation/net.rb:26:in `block in requ
est_with_newrelic_trace'
2014-10-18T18:09:33.971686+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/newrelic_rpm-3.8.1.221/lib/new_relic/agent/cross_app_tracing.rb:41:in `trace_http_requ
est'
2014-10-18T18:09:33.971687+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/newrelic_rpm-3.8.1.221/lib/new_relic/agent/instrumentation/net.rb:23:in `request_with_
newrelic_trace'
2014-10-18T18:09:33.971689+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/ruby-2.0.0/lib/ruby/2.0.0/net/http.rb:1126:in `get'
2014-10-18T18:09:33.971690+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/faraday-0.9.0/lib/faraday/adapter/net_http.rb:78:in `perform_request'
2014-10-18T18:09:33.971691+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/faraday-0.9.0/lib/faraday/adapter/net_http.rb:39:in `call'
2014-10-18T18:09:33.971693+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/faraday-0.9.0/lib/faraday/request/url_encoded.rb:15:in `call'
2014-10-18T18:09:33.971694+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/faraday-0.9.0/lib/faraday/rack_builder.rb:139:in `build_response'
2014-10-18T18:09:33.971695+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/faraday-0.9.0/lib/faraday/connection.rb:377:in `run_request'
2014-10-18T18:09:33.971696+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/oauth2-0.8.1/lib/oauth2/cli
ent.rb:88:in `request'
2014-10-18T18:09:33.971698+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/oauth2-0.8.1/lib/oauth2/access_token.rb:99:in `request'
2014-10-18T18:09:33.971699+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/oauth2-0.8.1/lib/oauth2/access_token.rb:106:in `get'
2014-10-18T18:09:33.971700+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/omniauth-facebook-access-token-0.1.3/lib/omniauth/strategies/facebook-access-token.rb:
90:in `callback_phase'
2014-10-18T18:09:33.971702+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/omniauth-1.2.1/lib/omniauth/strategy.rb:227:in `callback_call'
2014-10-18T18:09:33.971703+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/omniauth-1.2.1/lib/omniauth/strategy.rb:184:in `call!'
2014-10-18T18:09:33.971704+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/omniauth-1.2.1/lib/omniauth/strategy.rb:164:in `call'
2014-10-18T18:09:33.971706+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/omniauth-1.2.1/lib/omniauth/strategy.rb:186:in `call!'
2014-10-18T18:09:33.971707+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/omniauth-1.2.1/lib/omniauth/strategy.rb:164:in `call'
2014-10-18T18:09:33.971708+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/omniauth-1.2.1/lib/omniauth/builder.rb:59:in `call'
2014-10-18T18:09:33.971709+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/newrelic_rpm-3.8.1.221/lib/new_relic/rack/error_collector.rb:55:in `call'
2014-10-18T18:09:33.971711+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/newrelic_rpm-3.8.1.221/lib/new_relic/rack/agent_hooks.rb:32:in `call'
2014-10-18T18:09:33.971712+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/newrelic_rpm-3.8.1.221/lib/new_relic/rack/browser_monitoring.rb:27:in `call'
2014-10-18T18:09:33.971713+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/rack-ssl-1.4.1/lib/rack/ssl.rb:27:in `call'
2014-10-18T18:09:33.971714+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/warden-1.2.3/lib/warden/manager.rb:35:in `block in call'
2014-10-18T18:09:33.880979+00:00 app[web.1]: I, [2014-10-18T18:09:33.880840 #15]  INFO -- omniauth: (facebook_access_token) Callback phase initiated.
2014-10-18T18:09:33.971716+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/warden-1.2.3/lib/warden/manager.rb:34:in `catch' ``

I accidentally stumbled upon a tweet that mentioned facebook quietly dealt with the poodle vulnerability in some manner, and i have a feeling it has to do with what im experiencing. im not sure how to solve it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well basically, in case this happened to anyone -- I was using the omniauth-facebook gem, and something within that gem ( not sure where ) kept using sslv3 (even though facebook dropped it due to the POODLE vulnerability ). I simply switched to the koala gem instead and I was good to go!

Comment: Thanks for posting this answer @volk. So, were you using omniauth for user authentication with devise? I'm having the same issue as you, however, I don't see how I can use Koala as a replacement in that scenario. Thanks.

Comment: i was using omniauth-facebook in combination with omniauth-facebook-access-token gem (https://github.com/SoapSeller/omniauth-facebook-access-token). the only auth i had was confirming that a facebook access token was legitimate and then sent back a special auth token unique to my app. (its an iphone app)

Comment: Thanks @volk. I was able to solve my issue by just updating my gems to versions that were only depending on ssl v2. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26694173/existing-rails-4-heroku-app-suddenly-failing-with-sslv3-read-server-hello-a-ss

Comment: awesome @MattLong. I remembered I tried upgrading back then and it didn't work for me. I dont know why, but good to hear that it did for you!

Answer (score 0):

Check out this question, it probably has the solution you are looking for. Also you can turn off SSL verification, obviously not a good permanent solution but it will allow you to run your app temporarily

[How to get rid of OpenSSL::SSL::SSLError](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5711190/how-to-get-rid-of-opensslsslsslerror)

Comment: hey so i just tried adding this: 
:client_options => { :ssl => { :ca_path => "#{Rails.root}/lib/ssl/cacert.pem" } } 

and it didnt work :(

Comment: Try the no_verify option