# post_connection_check': hostname "ip" does not match the server certificate (OpenSSL::SSL::SSLError)

Tags: ruby, openssl

I tried to connect to remote server using REST method, in ruby I'm getting error as

```
/usr/lib/ruby/2.3.0/openssl/ssl.rb:315:in `post_connection_check': hostname "ip" does not match the server certificate (OpenSSL::SSL::SSLError)
        from /usr/lib/ruby/2.3.0/net/http.rb:944:in `connect'
        from /usr/lib/ruby/2.3.0/net/http.rb:863:in `do_start'
        from /usr/lib/ruby/2.3.0/net/http.rb:852:in `start'
        from /var/lib/gems/2.3.0/gems/rest-client-2.0.2/lib/restclient/request.rb:715:in `transmit'
        from /var/lib/gems/2.3.0/gems/rest-client-2.0.2/lib/restclient/request.rb:145:in `execute'
        from /var/lib/gems/2.3.0/gems/rest-client-2.0.2/lib/restclient/request.rb:52:in `execute'
        from /var/lib/gems/2.3.0/gems/rest-client-2.0.2/lib/restclient.rb:71:in `post'
```

this error occurred from the below line of code

```
require 'rest-client'

response        = RestClient.post(url, data, content_type: ctype)
```

I tried connecting to server using the openssl from command line as follows
I was able to connect to the server

```
openssl s_client -connect ip:port
```

How to solve this error as I am using ruby only. ( not rails )
please help me. Thanks in advance.

Comment: is the URL an "https" URL?

Comment: yes, it is being decided by the following line of code.
    scheme          = self.ssl ? "https" : "http"
    url             = "#{scheme}://#{host}:#{port}/#{uri}"

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to get rid of OpenSSL::SSL::SSLError](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5711190/how-to-get-rid-of-opensslsslsslerror)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`hostname "ip" does not match the server certificate (OpenSSL::SSL::SSLError)` means that the server certificate validation has some issue.

Depending on your situation, it can be OK to ignore it or not. In case you want to ignore it (note: insecure), use

```
response = RestClient.execute(method: :post, 
                              url: url, 
                              payload: data, 
                              verify_ssl: false, 
                              headers: { content_type: ctype })
```

See https://github.com/rest-client/rest-client/issues/288

Comment: i used "reposne = RestClient::Request.execute" it worked. Thanks.