# SSL_connect returned=1 errno=0 state=SSLv3 read server certificate B: certificate verify failed on WINDOWS

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, windows, ssl, openssl

After launching my server and going to localhost, I get the error:

```
SSL_connect returned=1 errno=0 state=SSLv3 read server certificate B: certificate verify failed
```

Tried the solutions here: http://railsapps.github.com/openssl-certificate-verify-failed.html and have been unable to get OpenSSL to update (it's at 0.9.8e).  I've downloaded multiple OpenSSL packages but none are being detected in my development environment.

Unable to use solution from: [SSL_connect returned=1 errno=0 state=SSLv3 read server certificate B: certificate verify failed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4528101/ssl-connect-returned-1-errno-0-state-sslv3-read-server-certificate-b-certificat) due to Windows OS.

Solutions here not working for me either: [How to solve "certificate verify failed" on Windows?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5720484/how-to-solve-certificate-verify-failed-on-windows)

What next steps should I take?

Comment: Look here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/34592316/615393

Answer (score 7):

try add the following line into your Gemfile

```
gem 'certified'
```

and execute

```
bundle
```

Run again!

Comment: nice use for development environment