# SSL_connect returned=1 errno=0 state=SSLv3 read server certificate B: certificate verify failed MAC

Tags: ruby, macos, sinatra, ssl-certificate

I'm attempting to use the SoundCloud SDK for user authentication. My first route after a user clicks "sign in":

```
get "/login" do 
    client = Soundcloud.new(:client_id => 'MY_ID',
                    :client_secret => 'MY_SECRET',
                    :redirect_uri => 'http://localhost:9393/signed_in')

redirect client.authorize_url()

end
```

I then have the next route where they are redirected:

```
get "/signed_in" do 
client = Soundcloud.new(:client_id => '16d6ada1a0cfc5009f7d59d203a13b2f',
                    :client_secret => '845df7d44dc4e359fedc8ed5944d29a5',
                    :redirect_uri => 'http://localhost:9393/signed_in')

code = params[:code]
access_token = client.exchange_token(:code => code)

end
```

I can succesfully hit the redirect url and a code is passed back, but I receieve the following error from Sinatra:

OpenSSL::SSL::SSLError at /signed_in
SSL_connect returned=1 errno=0 state=SSLv3 read server certificate B: certificate verify failed

I've read these popular articles: 
http://railsapps.github.io/openssl-certificate-verify-failed.html

[SSL_connect returned=1 errno=0 state=SSLv3 read server certificate B: certificate verify failed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4528101/ssl-connect-returned-1-errno-0-state-sslv3-read-server-certificate-b-certificat)

amongst many others

When I type:

```
rvm osx-ssl-certs status all
```

my result is 
Certificates for /usr/local/etc/openssl/cert.pem: Up to date.

I'm currently using ruby 2.1.1 on Mac 10.6.8. I've gone thru about 20 stack overflow questions on this topic and I'm unable to move past this issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Download http://curl.haxx.se/ca/ca-bundle.crt
2. Copy certificate into `/usr/local/etc/openssl/certs/`
3. Make omniauth.rb look like this:

   ```
   options = {
     scope: "email",
     :prompt => "select_account",
     access_type: 'offline',
     :client_options => {
       :ssl => {
         :ca_file => "/usr/local/etc/openssl/certs/ca-bundle.crt",
         :ca_path => "/usr/local/etc/openssl/certs"
       }
     }
   }

   Rails.application.config.middleware.use OmniAuth::Builder do
     provider :google_oauth2, Rails.application.secrets.client_id, Rails.application.secrets.client_secret, options
   end
   ```

Answer (score 0):

There is a gem to fix this issue, try adding `gem 'certified', '~> 1.0'`to your `Gemfile`.