# Mac - Faraday::SSLError: SSL_connect returned=1 errno=0 state=SSLv3 read server certificate B: certificate verify failed

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ssl, rubygems, faraday

I have tried so many ways to fix this.  Only seems to happen when calling https to google api.

Faraday.get "https://maps.googleapis.com/"

give me:
Faraday::SSLError: SSL_connect returned=1 errno=0 state=SSLv3 read server certificate B: certificate verify failed

Any ideas, all my certs seem ok - I can call other sites.

Thanks,
Daniel

Comment: have you tried any of these [Post1](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4528101/ssl-connect-returned-1-errno-0-state-sslv3-read-server-certificate-b-certificat),[Post2](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10728436/opensslsslsslerror-ssl-connect-returned-1-errno-0-state-sslv3-read-server-c),[Post3](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10775640/omniauth-facebook-error-faradayerrorconnectionfailed)<= references Faraday....etc Googling "ruby ssl connect returned 1 site:stackoverflow.com" returns 3000+ results (post what you have tried or try some of these options first)

Comment: [Here's another nice blog post too](http://web.archive.org/web/20120702091211/http://martinottenwaelter.fr/2010/12/ruby19-and-the-ssl-error/)

Comment: Look here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/34592316/615393