# Could not find json-1.8.3 in any of the sources Run `bundle install` to install missing gems

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, json

I am using a Windows 8 for development.  My problem started when I tried to install Ruby 2.2.2 using the Rails Installer, which was even epileptic to the source code am trying to clone.

I uninstalled RailsInstaller for Ruby2.2.2 and my old Ruby2.0.0 Development console started giving me problems/errors.

Here is the Error when I run bundle install:

```
Gem files will remain installed in F:/Rails
Programs/RubymineProjects/Rails-Bootstrap
Template/vendor/bundle/gems/json-1.8.3 for inspection. Results logged
to F:/Rails Programs/RubymineProjects/Rails-Bootstrap
Template/vendor/bundle/gems/json-1.8.3/ext/json/ext/generator/gem_make.out
An error occurred while installing json (1.8.3), and Bundler cannot
continue. Make sure that `gem install json -v '1.8.3'` succeeds before
bundling.
```

I also tried to install JSON as instructed, but also failed:

```
ERROR:  Could not find a valid gem 'json' (>= 0), here is why:
          Unable to download data from https://rubygems.org/ - SSL_connect returned=1 errno=0 state=SSLv3 read server certificate B:
certificate verify failed (https://rubygems.org/l atest_specs.4.8.gz)
```

I have tried virtually everything I found relating to this but all to no avail.

A few things I tampered with are DevKit, which I set to Ruby 2.2.2 but I reconfigured it to Ruby 2.0.0 after uninstalling Ruby 2.2.2.

Comment: I also did run bundle exec rails s
All I have is: 

Could not find json-1.8.3 in any of the sources
Run `bundle install` to install missing gems.

Comment: The SSL error you're seeing is actually the problem.  you might try: http://stackoverflow.com/a/16134586/1753596

Comment: [JSON is bundled with Ruby](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.3.0/libdoc/json/rdoc/index.html). Why are you trying to reinstall it? You "tried virtually everything" but we have no idea what that means. You need to give us an idea so we don't waste time shooting in the dark suggesting things you've already tried. Finally, be wary when following directions on the web. If the page is old, even a year old, it's likely to be somewhat out of date. A page that's two years old is even more likely to be stale and can give you bad directions. [ask]

Comment: When I run my rails server, it gives me this error.
I have posted the error I receive when i try to bundle install, which is the reason i had to reinstall JSON as instructed. 
Reinstalling JSON also prompt SSL error.

Comment: What happens in IRB if you enter `require 'json'`?

Comment: @theTinMan, Thanks for editing.

When I run rails server, I get the error:
Could not find json-1.8.3 in any of the sources

I proceed to run gem list and I found json in my Local Gems, but for some reasons, I have the error:


Could not find json-1.8.3 in any of the sources

Comment: @theTinMan, it returns TRUE

Comment: Thanks @theTinMan, I figured it out. I will like suggestions of resources from you that could/can make me learn better as Ruby on Rails Developer. I will wait for your response. Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here are the steps I have taken to solve the problem.

1. I removed all json entries from Gemfile.lock, then
2. I did run `bundle install`, then
3. start server by running `rails server`

and it worked. Thanks.