# Ruby Smartsheet certificate verify failed

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, smartsheet-api

I am trying to make use of [smartsheet](https://rubygems.org/gems/smartsheet/versions/1.0.0) rubygem to connect to smartsheet account and fetch the sheet list.

I used following code

```
client = Smartsheet::Client.new(token: ACCESS_TOKEN)
sheets = client.sheets.list
```

On line 2, I am getting below error.

```
Smartsheet::RequestError: SSL_connect returned=1 errno=0 state=error: certificate verify failed
        from app/models/smartsheet_client.rb:18:in `get_sheets'
        from (irb):5
```

I am executing this code from local, what I am missing?
Any suggestions much appreciated.
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm no Ruby expert, but it seems like this error means that your code isn't able to verify that the SSL certificate of the site that you're connecting to is valid. I'd suspect that this issue is being caused by a problem with the config of your local dev environment, not a problem with the **smartsheet** rubygem.

The following posts specify several possible solutions to this problem:

- [SO post: How to solve “certificate verify failed” on Windows?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5720484/how-to-solve-certificate-verify-failed-on-windows)
- [Engine Yard post: Ruby SSL Error: Certificate Verify Failed](https://www.engineyard.com/blog/ruby-ssl-error-certificate-verify-failed)

I'd suggest that you review these posts and comment here if one of the proposed solutions works for you (for the benefit of others in the future).

Comment: Excellent! Happy I could help out.