# Unable to install Ruby-Debug-Ide

Tags: ruby, rubygems, ruby-debug-ide

I have a problem with the installation of Ruby-Debug-Ide Gem.
I dont know how to fix this. Can someone help me ? Thank your very much !!

```
Microsoft Windows [Version 6.1.7601]
Copyright (c) 2009 Microsoft Corporation. Alle Rechte vorbehalten.

C:\Users>ruby --version
ruby 2.3.0p0 (2015-12-25 revision 53290) [x64-mingw32]

C:\Users>gem install debase -s http://rubygems.org/
Fetching: debase-0.2.2.gem (100%)
Temporarily enhancing PATH to include DevKit...
Building native extensions.  This could take a while...
Successfully installed debase-0.2.2
Parsing documentation for debase-0.2.2
Installing ri documentation for debase-0.2.2
Done installing documentation for debase after 1 seconds
WARNING:  Unable to pull data from 'https://rubygems.org/': SSL_connect returned
=1 errno=0 state=SSLv3 read server certificate B: certificate verify failed (htt
ps://api.rubygems.org/specs.4.8.gz)
1 gem installed

C:\Users>gem list

*** LOCAL GEMS ***

bigdecimal (1.2.8)
debase (0.2.3.beta5, 0.2.2)
debase-ruby_core_source (0.10.4)
did_you_mean (1.0.0)
io-console (0.4.5)
json (1.8.3)
minitest (5.8.3)
net-telnet (0.1.1)
power_assert (0.2.6)
psych (2.0.17)
rake (12.3.2, 10.4.2)
rdoc (4.2.1)
test-unit (3.1.5)

C:\Users>gem install ruby-debug-ide  -s http://rubygems.org/
Fetching: ruby-debug-ide-0.6.1.gem (100%)
Temporarily enhancing PATH to include DevKit...
Building native extensions.  This could take a while...
ERROR:  Error installing ruby-debug-ide:
        ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

    current directory: C:/Ruby23-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/ruby-debug-ide-0.6
.1/ext
C:/Ruby23-x64/bin/ruby.exe mkrf_conf.rb
Installing base gem
Unable to resolve dependency: user requested 'debase (> 0)'
C:/Ruby23-x64/lib/ruby/2.3.0/rubygems/resolver.rb:234:in `search_for'
  C:/Ruby23-x64/lib/ruby/2.3.0/rubygems/resolver/molinillo/lib/molinillo/resolut
ion.rb:130:in `block (2 levels) in <class:Resolution>'
  C:/Ruby23-x64/lib/ruby/2.3.0/rubygems/resolver/molinillo/lib/molinillo/resolut
ion.rb:180:in `initial_state'
  C:/Ruby23-x64/lib/ruby/2.3.0/rubygems/resolver/molinillo/lib/molinillo/resolut
ion.rb:99:in `start_resolution'
  C:/Ruby23-x64/lib/ruby/2.3.0/rubygems/resolver/molinillo/lib/molinillo/resolut
ion.rb:62:in `resolve'
  C:/Ruby23-x64/lib/ruby/2.3.0/rubygems/resolver/molinillo/lib/molinillo/resolve
r.rb:41:in `resolve'
  C:/Ruby23-x64/lib/ruby/2.3.0/rubygems/resolver.rb:191:in `resolve'
  C:/Ruby23-x64/lib/ruby/2.3.0/rubygems/request_set.rb:363:in `resolve'
  C:/Ruby23-x64/lib/ruby/2.3.0/rubygems/dependency_installer.rb:484:in `resolve_
dependencies'
  C:/Ruby23-x64/lib/ruby/2.3.0/rubygems/dependency_installer.rb:384:in `install'

  mkrf_conf.rb:35:in `rescue in <main>'
  mkrf_conf.rb:28:in `<main>'

rake failed, exit code 1

Gem files will remain installed in C:/Ruby23-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/ruby-d
ebug-ide-0.6.1 for inspection.
Results logged to C:/Ruby23-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/extensions/x64-mingw32/2.3.0
/ruby-debug-ide-0.6.1/gem_make.out

C:\Users>
```

I tried this very often, also with other vesions of ruby but it still doesnt work. I am using now Windows 7 and Ruby 2.3.0. I have also the DevKit installed. Is there a special command so that the Installation of Ruby-Debug-Ide can resolve Debase ?

Comment: Did you try to install other version of gem? For example `gem install ruby-debug-ide -v 0.7.0.beta7`

Comment: Also read answer [about SSL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5720484/how-to-solve-certificate-verify-failed-on-windows)

Comment: Yes i tried, but it didnt work anyway