# What is Liquid Exception 'certificate verify failed'?

Tags: ruby, ssl, rubygems, jekyll

I am designing Jekyll site in localhost but when I add github_sample tag and try to include a code block from the repo I got this error:

```
Liquid Exception: SSL_connect returned=1 errno=0 state=error: certificate verify failed (unable to get local issuer certificate) in solution/solution.md
jekyll 3.8.6 | Error:  SSL_connect returned=1 errno=0 state=error: certificate verify failed (unable to get local issuer certificate)
```

Comment: Which Jekyll theme and OS do you use?

Comment: jekyll-theme-hacker and Windows 10

Comment: Can you add some sample code, it is unclear what do you mean by github_sample tag. Do you refer to https://github.com/bwillis/jekyll-github-sample?

Comment: @Christian Yes, I added sample code.

Answer (score 0):

The error *certificate verify failed (unable to get local issuer certificate)* is an indication that the root certificates on the system are not working correctly and this does not seem to be a Jekyll issue.

Found a potential solution [here](https://github.com/mzlogin/mzlogin.github.io/wiki/Problems-and-solutions-when-run-Jekyll-on-Windows):

**Problem**

SSL_connect returned=1 errno=0 state=SSLv3 read server certificate B: certificate verify failed

**Solution**

1. Download https://curl.haxx.se/ca/cacert.pem
2. Add a environment variable SSL_CERT_FILE values /path/to/cacert.pem

Comment: I added environment variable SSL_CERT_FILE but not working yet.

Comment: I have tested the theme locally with the [github sample](https://github.com/bwillis/jekyll-github-sample#example-usage) and could not see an ssl error. I think the problem is related to you ruby installation somehow. See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5720484/how-to-solve-certificate-verify-failed-on-windows), there is a good test with open-uri included. I suggest to go back to this page and try again installing ruby from the scratch (https://jekyllrb.com/docs/installation/windows/). The cacert.pem file is part of the ruby installer.