# SSL certificate issue with implementing facebook login via Omniauth - Windows machines

Tags: ruby-on-rails, facebook, authentication, openssl, omniauth

I am facing the same issue as described here - 
[OmniAuth & Facebook: certificate verify failed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3977303/omniauth-facebook-certificate-verify-failed/5618072#5618072)

The most voted answer suggests adding the following to your Omniauth initializer:

```
Rails.application.config.middleware.use OmniAuth::Builder do
    provider :facebook, FACEBOOK_KEY, FACEBOOK_SECRET, {:client_options => {:ssl => {:ca_path => "/etc/ssl/certs"}}}
end
```

However he mentions "/etc/ssl/certs" is the CA_PATH for ubuntu.
What is the relevant CA_PATH for an windows ?

If there is no certificate on my machine , how do I install one and where do I put the certificate file ?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

This is how I solved the issue -

I downloaded this file - http://certifie.com/ca-bundle/ca-bundle.crt.txt and put in my app/config folder.

I renamed the file as ca-bundle.crt

I updated my omniauth initializer to relfect the following -

```
Rails.application.config.middleware.use OmniAuth::Builder do
    provider :facebook, FACEBOOK_KEY, FACEBOOK_SECRET, :client_options => { :ssl => { :ca_file => "#{Rails.root}/config/ca-bundle.crt" } } 
end
```

And it worked.

Comment: do you know if this still working. Im getting this issue but this fix is not working for me

Comment: It works ! Thanks for the solution. I found another solution but that didn't work yet there are lots of people who gave a vote to that answer.

Comment: I got the following message in my dev env (localhost Windows) "Given URL is not allowed by the Application configuration.: One or more of the given URLs is not allowed by the App's settings. It must match the Website URL or Canvas URL, or the domain must be a subdomain of one of the App's domains." Any ideas?

Comment: The message above came because I was using 'localhost' and registered '127.0.0.1' at Facebook. Now I'm getting the original error again