# Rails 3, Facebook, Koala: NoMethodError: undefined method `closed?' for nil:NilClass

Tags: ruby-on-rails, facebook, koala

seems I get this error from Koala when I'm trying to connect with the graph api:
NoMethodError: undefined method `closed?' for nil:NilClass

It is exactly the same problem I had before with Omniauth which can be read here:
https://github.com/intridea/omniauth/issues/260
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3977303/omniauth-facebook-certificate-verify-failed

basically is that Faraday is not setting the ca_path variable for OpenSSL. One solution is:
OpenSSL::SSL::VERIFY_PEER = OpenSSL::SSL::VERIFY_NONE

in Omniauth the solution was putting an option like this:
provider :facebook, FACEBOOK_KEY, FACEBOOK_SECRET, {:client_options => {:ssl => {:ca_path => "/etc/ssl/certs"}}}

I was wondering if anybody else has have the problem and how was it solved. I wouldn't like to use the first option and the second one is not possible afaik in koala.

I'm using Koala 1.2.0 and Faraday 0.7.4

thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems it is possible to set default options for ssl in Koala.

[github.com/arsduo/koala/wiki/HTTP-Services](http://github.com/arsduo/koala/wiki/HTTP-Services)

I just missed it!