# Upgrade OpenSSL for OS 10.5 failed: flipscanister

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, macos, openssl

I am trying to update my OpenSSL 0.9.71 to latest version to avoid [error with Devise & Facebook login](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3977303/omniauth-facebook-certificate-verify-failed). Since it is not easy to update OpenSSL, I have to install another version of OpenSSL from source. I was able to follow these steps:

```
cd /users/<your_user_name>/desktop/
sudo mv openssl /usr/local/
sudo cd /usr/local/openssl
./config
```

When I run

```
make
```

I got the following error:

```
unable to find /usr/local/ssl/lib/fips-1.0//flipscanister.o
```

I spent a day searching around but I couldn't find any help to install flipcanister, so my questions are:

1. Do I need to install new OpenSSL, or there is a way to get around it with older version(i.e., just copy a few files to the right location)?
2. If I have to, then how should I install flipscanister

Thank you very much for your help.

Comment: You could probably save yourself a lot of trouble by installing Rails and openssl using MacPorts.  It still supports OS X 10.5.  http://www.macports.org/